# Where is my docker directory on my Macbook

Tags: docker

I am following a docker tutorial which says the docker host installation creates a directory with path `/var/lib/docker`. I am using MacBook. My Docker host is up and running already, but I don't see the directory `docker/` under `/var/lib/` . how can I find where is the docker folder on my Macbook? Why it is not under `/var/lib/docker` like the tutorial says?

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS should be `~/Library/Containers`. The `/var/lib/docker` refers to Linux.

Comment: But under `/var/lib/docker` in Linux there are `images`, `containers`, `volumes` folders. Why your answer directly give the `Containers`? My point is to find the `docker` directory which contains all those

Comment: And did you check this directory?

Comment: Yes, I checked but like I said in my previous comment I wonder where are the `images` and `volumes` directories as well. Because in Linux under `/var/lib/docker` there are `images`,`containers` and `volumes` directories.

Comment: Everything should be in there https://forums.docker.com/t/where-are-images-stored-on-mac-os-x/17165